# listCollection returns empty when using javascript sdk while it was created through python using boto3

Tags: aws-sdk, boto3, amazon-rekognition

I created a collection using boto3 with following code:

```
rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition',
        aws_access_key_id="__myclientId",
        aws_secret_access_key="__secret"
)
rekognition.create_collection(
     CollectionId='myPhotos'
)
```

which is appearing as created when I fetch it using the following code in python boto3:

```
response = rekognition.list_collections()
print(response)
```

But when I try to fetch the same collection using Javascript SDK "aws-sdk" in nodeJs using following code I get empty results:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId : "__myclientId",
            secretAccessKey : "__secret",
            region: "us-east-1"
});

let rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition();
rekognition.listCollections({}, function (err, data)
{
     console.log(err, data);
});
```

**RESPONSE JS:**

```
{ CollectionIds: [], FaceModelVersions: [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it was missing the region in first code. Because of missing region it assumes some default region and because of that the collection doesn't show up when search for it in us-east-1 region to solve this need to pass region like this:

```
rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition',
        aws_access_key_id="__myclientId",
        aws_secret_access_key="__secret",
        region_name= "us-east-1"
)
```